# React Native Can't find variable: route

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Error using route params

Hi everyone, I am starting to use react native. I have the backend done and now I am about to finish with the front. But I have problem using route params.

What I have is the following:

APP
I am using native-base v3,
@react-navigation / native,
@react-navigation / stack
as you can see to play with the views

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

import Login from './views/Login';
import CrearCuenta from './views/CrearCuenta';
import Proyectos from './views/Proyectos';
import NuevoProyecto from './views/NuevoProyecto';
import Proyecto from './views/Proyecto';


const App = () => {
  return (

        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">

            <Stack.Screen
              name="Login"
              component={Login}
              options={{
                title: "Iniciar Sesión",
                headerShown: false
              }}
            />

            <Stack.Screen
              name="CrearCuenta"
              component={CrearCuenta}
              options={{
                title: "Crear Cuenta",
                headerStyle:{
                  backgroundColor: '#e76e51'
                },
                headerTintColor: '#FFF',
                headerTitleStyle:{
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
              }}
            />

            <Stack.Screen
              name="Proyectos"
              component={Proyectos}
              options={{
                title: "Proyectos",
                headerStyle:{
                  backgroundColor: '#e76e51'
                },
                headerTintColor: '#FFF',
                headerTitleStyle:{
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
              }}
            />

            <Stack.Screen
              name="NuevoProyecto"
              component={NuevoProyecto}
              options={{
                title: "Nuevo Proyecto",
                headerStyle:{
                  backgroundColor: '#e76e51'
                },
                headerTintColor: '#FFF',
                headerTitleStyle:{
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
              }}
            />

            <Stack.Screen
              name="Proyecto"
              component={Proyecto}
              options={ ({route}) => ({
                title: route.params.nombre,
                headerStyle:{
                  backgroundColor: '#e76e51'
                },
                headerTintColor: '#FFF',
                headerTitleStyle:{
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
              })}
            />
            
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>

  );
};


export default App;
```

You can see that I have a login, sign up, create projects and create tasks for each project.
Everything works: I can create a user, that user can create projects (whatever he wants) and when I enter a project I have the option to create tasks.

In the backend I have associated that when a task is created, this task belongs to its project and its corresponding user.

Next I show you what I have in the project view, which is where the task is created.

PROYECTO

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import {
  Box,
  Text,
  Heading,
  VStack,
  FormControl,
  Input,
  Button,
  HStack,
  Center,
  NativeBaseProvider,
  Toast
} from "native-base"
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import glogalStyles from "../styles/global";

// Apollo
import {gql, useMutation} from '@apollo/client';

// Crear nuevas tareas
const NUEVA_TAREA = gql `
mutation nuevaTarea($input: TareaInput){
      nuevaTarea(input: $input) {
          nombre
          id
          proyecto
          estado
      }
  }
`;

export const Example = () => {
    
    // state componente
    const [ nombre, guardarNombre ] = useState('');
    const [ mensaje, guardarMensaje ] = useState(null);

    // apollo
    const [ nuevaTarea ] = useMutation(NUEVA_TAREA);

    // Validation and create task
    const handleSubmit = async () => {

        if(nombre === ''){
            guardarMensaje('El nombre de la tarea es obligatorio');
            return;
        }

        // save BBDD
        try {
            const { data } = await nuevaTarea({
                variables: {
                    input: {
                        nombre,
                        proyecto: route.params.id
                    }
                }
            });

            console.log(data);
            guardarNombre('');
            guardarMensaje('Tarea creada correctamente');

            setTimeout( () => {
                guardarMensaje(null);
            }, 3000);

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error al crear tarea');
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    // mshow mensaje toast
    const mostrarAlerta = () => {
        Toast.show({
        description: mensaje,
        buttonText: 'OK',
        duration: 4000
        })
    }
    
    const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Box safeArea p="2" py="8" w="90%" maxW="290">

      <VStack space={3} mt="5">
          
        <FormControl>
            <FormControl.Label>Agregar tareas</FormControl.Label>
                <Input
                    value = {nombre}
                    onChangeText={ texto => guardarNombre(texto) }
                />
        </FormControl>

        <Button 
          
          onPress={ () => handleSubmit() }
        >
          <Text>
            crear tarea
          </Text>
        </Button>

        {mensaje && mostrarAlerta()}

      </VStack>
    </Box>
  )
}

const Proyecto = ({route}) => {
    console.log(route.params);
    return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
            <Center
                //flex={1}
                px="3"
            >
                <Example />
            </Center>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
    );
}
 
export default Proyecto;
```

I get the error when saving in the DB, specifically here:

```
try {
            const { data } = await nuevaTarea({
                variables: {
                    input: {
                        nombre,
                        proyecto: route.params.id
                    }
                }
            });
```

In the terminal I have the error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn5kW.png)

I have declared {route} in const Proyecto = ({route}) => {
.....
}
That inside Proyecto calls Example

I've tried putting {route} in Example's function, but it doesn't work either, even with this.params.id

In my backend in the schema, input TaskInput returns the name and the project, the 2 as String! required.

Thank you soo much.